# Multiple sequential cURL xml POST requests to API with PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl, post

I have an array of ids called $enabled as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 374468
    [1] => 406927
    [2] => 177652
    [3] => 488233
    [4] => 167711
    [5] => 166049
    [6] => 492313
    [7] => 166499
    [8] => 489315
    [9] => 396740
    [10] => 167639
```

etc...

I also have an xml file 'GetProperty.xml', as follows (values omitted for security):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scAPI>
  <client>
    <ID></ID>
    <key></key>
    <siteID></siteID>
    <propertyID></propertyID>
  </client>
</scAPI>
```

Lastly, I have a PHP method which posts the xml to the desired endpoint, and which accepts two arguments (the xml as $xmlstr and the endpoint as $url):

```
class apiClass {

    public function curl($xmlpost, $url) {

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $xmlpost
    ));

        if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
        {
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }

        $xml = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $xml;

    }

}
```

I now need to:

1. take each ID in turn
2. edit the value of the propertyID node in the xml to match the ID
3. and then POST that XML to the desired endpoint using the curl method

I need to iterate through the ID array with a foreach loop to POST each ID in turn (or do something altogether different if there is a better way).

Thank you for help, in advance.

Comment: Maybe, keep an XML template in memory and insert the ID into it?

Comment: @user4035 Thanks for the tip. What would you recommend - something like APC / Memcache?